# htaccess multiple query strings strip out

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to rewrite old url with query string to new one. Tried over 20 different variations and most don't work or give me internal server error

Original URL:

`/got_forms/?List=keywordsearch&MyKeyWordSearch=Malcom`

I need this to rewrite as

`/members/forms-publication-keyword/Malcom`

Issue I am having is that no matter what I try `?List=keywordsearch&MyKeyWordSearch` comes thru.

Some of the different ways I tried to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^List=([0-9]{4})&MyKeyWordSearch=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^publ_forms\/?$ /members/forms-publication-keyword/%2? [L]
```

Did not work.

```
RewriteRule ^/got_forms.*MyKeyWordSearch=(.*) http://www.domain.com/members/forms-publication-keyword/$1
```

Did not work.

```
#RewriteRule ^/got_forms/$       /members/forms-publication-keyword/        [NC,L,R=301]
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^MyKeyWordSearch=(.*)$    [NC]
#RewriteRule ^/got_forms/$      /members/forms-publication-keyword/%1      [NC,L,R=301]
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^List=keywordsearch&MyKeyWordSearch=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^got_forms/?$ members/forms-publication-keyword/%1? [L,NC,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Not doing it or I am totally off in understanding. Once I put that in I try to access:
www.domain.com/got_forms/?List=keywordsearch&MyKeyWordSearch=Malcom and what it returns is 
www.domain.com/got_forms?List=keywordsearch&MyKeyWordSearch=Malcom 

and Page Not Found. So its only removing / after forms

Comment: I am expecting that it would return 
www.domain.com/members/forms-publication-keyword/Malcom

Comment: It works except in cases where its not a single word. If I use Malcom it works however when its =Malcom Wallace it returns an extra charachter

Malcom%2520Wallace  

Looks like it accounts an extra for space?